# Keeping flash drive safe in daily usage

Tags: storage, safety

Everyone has some things like, they should always have with them, mobile phone, wallet, calendar, etc.

In my case, I also have a USB flash drive, where all my data is stored, which I need every day in school and maybe at any time.

At the moment, I keep my flash drive in my pencil case, but it would be better to keep it somewhere else, where it can't get lost easily and can't be stolen.

I thought about making a necklace with my flash drive but I don't know how I could do that. It's also not possible to keep it in my wallet, it may fall out easily.

Has anyone ideas where I could keep my flash drive or what I can create so that I can have it always with me, and not having the risk to lose it.

[image]

(Hope that this is the right SE site)

Comment: As an aside, it is vitally important that you copy the contents of your flash drive to a backup on a regular basis if it is that important to you.There are many ways in which you could lose this data, where would you be then?

Comment: @Lefty I already do that.

Comment: Could a teacher or some other staff member keep it for you in a locked room when you have a break or are off to lunch?

Comment: @SerafinaReisinger It would be better if you provide us an image of your flash drive, to find out more hacks.

Comment: You might consider using your phone as a flash drive, especially if you have an Android with a microSD card slot. By plugging your phone into the computer, you could access your phone's memory and even the internal card's memory. (I can post an answer later if anyone's interested)

Comment: You could also ditch the USB drive and use an online solution like DropBox or GoogleDrive.  These can be installed on your home computer as if htey are a USB drive, but then you can access them via a website when you are on the move.  I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer, because it doesn't address the "USB drive safety" question.

Comment: @computercarguy Yeah, some people of my class already do that but that leads to many problems when there's no internet connection. The teachers don't like this excuse a lot,

Answer (score 12):

There are USB flash drives that that are designed to be carried on a key chain (or necklace).

If you can't or don't want to invest in a new drive, get a small pouch which can be securely attached to your clothes/keychain/bag.

Comment: I had the same approach. Many folks at my workplace keep their flash drive in their ID cards, while other's keep it as necklace or keychain as answered by @Halin

Answer (score 2):

I have a USB like this with me. Haven't lost on me and very handy. :) I put it like baller bands. It is waterproof because its lid is made of soft rubber.

[image: Baller Flash Drive]

Answer (score 0):

I have already commented to show your type of flash drive. Since there are a lot of varieties, we need to see the one in order to ponder about likely hacks for it.
Anyway, I am adding up two ideas that could be applied generally.

- Customize a retractable id card holder to attach your flash drive. Most of the flash drives in the market have a hole at its tail, in order to hang it up. Use the same to hang it up to your pants. Also, I believe, most of them are durable to hits that may happen if you hang it outside the pant. If needed, you can retract it to the inside of your pants pocket too. The point is that you always remember as it is hanging outside your pant.

[image]

- You can hang the same with ID card holder that goes around your neck.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

The flash drive you show has a slot on the bottom you can thread a thin string through. You can use that to attach the flash drive to something (necklace, lanyard, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to not lose a flash drive's contents (because it is the contents that interest you and not the drive itself) is to regularly keep backups. I would recommend having a second flash drive and weekly (or daily, depends on how often you add or modify it's contents) copy the contents of the first drive to the second. Keep the backup drive in a safe place at home. So if you lose your original drive, your data will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your drive is safe, your data is not. Flash drives do go bad. They may also be broken while in the computer by some accident. You need a backup solution to a cloud service. There are many.

Answer (score -2):

In the spirit of christmas, I give you the final solution.

https://m.alibaba.com/showroom/tooth-implant-usb-flash-drive.html

[image: foo]

This is called biohacking, and is much more useful than piercing. Gone are the days when a man or woman would old-school hide stuff in their cavities, now implants are all the rage.